# Avoid duplicity on Jenkins Job DSL API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I´m configuring a couple Jenkins jobs using **Jenkins Job DSL Plugin**, and in the steps section for my two jobs it´s almost the same, just has to change one value "**builder**" by "**couchbase**".

For now seems like I´m breaking DRY and I´m duplicating a lot of code. Since I´m pretty newby on DSL I´m not quite sure if the API allow create a sort of generic code to avoid duplicate steps as I´m doing.

```
job("images/builder") {
   concurrentBuild()
   triggers {
      githubPush()
 }

scm {
    git {
        remote {
            github("aws", "https", "github.dev.global.com")
            credentials('***********')
        }
    }
}
steps {
    shell('export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1')
    shell('$(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)')
    shell('docker build -t builder -f ./images/builder/Dockerfile .')
    shell('docker tag -f builder:latest **********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/builder:latest')
    shell('docker push **********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/builder:latest)')
}

}

job("images/couchbase") {
   concurrentBuild()
    triggers {
    githubPush()
   }

scm {
    git {
        remote {
               github("aws2", "https", "github.dev.global.com")

            credentials('****************')
        }
    }
}
steps {
    shell('export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1')
    shell('$(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)')
    shell('docker build -t builder -f ./images/couchbase/Dockerfile .')
    shell('docker tag -f builder:latest ********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/couchbase:latest')
    shell('docker push **********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/couchbase:latest)')
}

}
```

Comment: Job DSL is built based on [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/), so it's possible to mix it with Groovy code to add more logic into seed job. And in result to follow DRY rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's as simple as the same steps for two named projects, a loop would suffice:

```
String[] names = ["builder", "couchbase"]

names.each {
  job("images/" + it) {
    concurrentBuild()
    triggers {
      githubPush()
    }

    scm {
      git {
        remote {
          github("aws2", "https", "github.dev.global.com")

          credentials('****************')
        }
      }
    }
    steps {
      shell('export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1')
      shell('$(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)')
      shell('docker build -t builder -f ./images/' + it + '/Dockerfile .')
      shell('docker tag -f builder:latest ********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + it + ':latest')
      shell('docker push **********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + it + ':latest)')
    }

  }
}
```

If you want something more complex, take a look at [these examples](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example), specifically the [job builder class](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/dslexample/GradleCiJobBuilder.groovy) and [usage of it](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/blob/master/jobs/example7Jobs.groovy)